# Convert JSON to GSON

Tags: android, json, parsing, localhost, gson

I'm developing this app which after the user logs in and presses the submit button, it checks it with my localhost. So far, everything is fine. For parsing the data from `localhost`, I had to use `JSON`. However, it happens that the query does NOT contain the square brackets. Hence I decided to use `GSON` to parse the data. For sake of testing the functionality of the application, there's only one query in my `localhost` which is : `{ 'Android' :{'statues':'1'}}` and the only value I want to parse is statues.

Question is, how am I gonna do that? Is using `GSON` a correct choice or there's another way?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing a few things here.

You've obviously developed a REST service that your Android app "talks to" via JSON. JSON is a data format with a defined syntax. If this syntax is incorrect, that's bad. If the syntax is bad coming from the app, your service should throw a 400 (Bad Request) back to your app. If it is bad coming from the service, fix your bug. You can't worry about anything else until you resolve your syntax issues.

Now when it comes time to parse the JSON in your app, you have many libraries at your disposal for serializing Java objects and deserializing JSON. GSON is one. [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML) is another. There are many others. Which is "better" is a matter of opinion. Choose whichever feels easiest, satisfies what you need, and is actively maintained.

The weird thing is your JSON seems to have data where metadata should be. I think it should look like this:

```
{ 'phoneType' : 'Android', 'statues': 1}
```

And you'd have this

```
public class MyObject {
  private String phoneType;
  private int statues;

  //getters and setters
}
```

Then to use GSON, you would do something like this:

```
MyObject o = gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your concerns.
This sound perfectly fine and it actually solved a lot of my dilemmas and ambiguous points.
Thanks again

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!

Comment: btw, if I use the class (MyObject), how can I relate it to my local host? it catches the values from the class. Does gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class) do the work?

Comment: I don't get the question. When you get the JSON from a source, you pass it along with the Java class representation you want to `gson.fromJson`. Then your Java object will have all the data that were in the JSON.